# How to union two igraphs objects without using data.frames?

Tags: r, igraph

Let's say I have two graphs: `net1` and `net2` with same names of nodes. I'd like to union `net1` and `net2` into one graph `net` and then add a new edge from node `A` to node `A` where the first node `A` from the component `net1` and the second node `A` from the component `net2`.  I have tried:

```
library(igraph)
net1 <- graph_from_literal(A-B-C)
net2 <- graph_from_literal(A-B-C)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

plot(net1, main="net1")
plot(net2, main="net2")

head <- "A"
tail <- "A"

AddEdge <- c( which(V(net1)$name == head), 
              which(V(net2)$name == tail))

net <- union(net1, net2)
#net <- graph.union(net1, net2, byname=F)
#net <- graph.union(net1, net2, byname=T)

# add edge
net <- add_edges(net, AddEdge, color = "red")
plot(net, main="union net1 and net2")
```

[image]

I'm looking for a buid-in function like `function_union(net1, net2)`.

**Question.** Is it possible to union two igraphs objects without transformation into a `data.frame` object and back to an `igraphs` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you union on the same vertices, the 2 graphs, being identical, collapse into 1 graph. Suggestion is to create 2 different graph with different vertices but identical labels, union then plot.

```
library(igraph)
net1 <- graph_from_literal(A1-B1-C1)
net2 <- graph_from_literal(A2-B2-C2)

#union the 2 graphs and update the color of the edges
net <- union(net1, net2)
E(net)$color <- "gray"

#link the 2 graphs
net <- add_edges(net, which(V(net)$name %in% c("A1", "A2")), color="red")

#update the labels of the union graph
V(net)$label <- substr(V(net)$name, 1, 1)

#plot the union graph
plot(net, main="union net1 and net2")
```